# WebApi POST Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to call a post method and i get 405 / Method not Allowed.

Here is my code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string PostUsers(string user)
    {
        return user;

    }
```

How i make the request

```
this.data.append('user', JSON.stringify(this.user));
            var user= this.data;
            console.log(equipo);
            axios.post('/api/apiEquipos', user).then((response) => {

                console.log('Ok')
            }).catch(errors => {
                if(typeof errors.response.data === 'object'){
                    this.errors = _.flatten(_.toArray(errors.response.data))
                }else{
                    this.errors = ['Error'];
                }
            })
```

If i call the method thought POSTMAN its run well

WebApiConfig

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you specified routing for the C# endpoint? If not, it looks like you're hitting the wrong endpoint.

Comment: Do you send body as `JSON` from POSTMAN?

Comment: yes, i add the param user and value as JSON and works well

Comment: Are you sure that requests from POSTMAN and from JS are same? Are urls identical? You can add `[FromBody]` - `PostUsers([FromBody] string user)` -  in action parameter. But if it works from POSTMAN it should work from JS.

Comment: if i add the [FromBody] string user its send the error 415 / Unsupported Media Type

Comment: Try to change this part `axios.post('/api/apiEquipos', user)` to this `axios.post('/api/apiEquipos', JSON.stringify(user))`. Also, use `[FromBody]` in action